# What is the conventional way to convert a range of bits to an integer value in c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, hex, byte, bitarray

I've been programming for many years, but have never needed to use bitwise operations too much or really deal with data too much on a bit or even byte level, until now.  So, please forgive my lack of knowledge.

I'm having to process streaming message frame data that I'm getting via socket communication.  The message frames are a series of hex bytes encoded Big Endian which I read into a byte array called byteArray.  Take the following 2 bytes for example:

**0x03 0x20**

The data I need is represented in the first 14 bits - meaning I need to convert the first 14 bits into an int value.  (The last 2 bits represent 2 other bool values).  I have coded the following to accomplish this:

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    Array.Reverse(byteArray);
}

BitArray bitArray = GetBitArrayFromRange(new BitArray(byteArray), 0, 14);

int dataValue = GetIntFromBitArray(bitArray)
```

The **dataValue** variable ends up with the correct result which is: **800**

The two functions I'm calling are here:

```
    private static BitArray GetBitArrayFromRange(BitArray bitArray, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        var newBitArray = new BitArray(length);

        for (int i = startIndex; i < length; i++)
        {
            newBitArray[i] = bitArray.Get(i);
        }

        return newBitArray;
    }

    private static int GetIntFromBitArray(BitArray bitArray)
    {
        int[] array = new int[1];

        bitArray.CopyTo(array, 0);

        return array[0];
    }
```

Since I have a lack of experience in this area, my question is: Does this code look correct/reasonable? Or, is there a more preferred/conventional way of accomplishing what I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> *"The dataValue variable ends up with the correct result which is: **800**"*

Shouldn't that *correct result* be actually **200**?

1) 00000011 00100001 : is integer `0x0321` (so now skip beginning two bits `01`...)

2) xx000000 11001000 : is extracted last 14 bits (missing 2 bits, so those `xx` count as zero)

3) 00000000 11001000 : is expected final result from 14-bits extraction = **200**

At present it looks like you have an empty (zero filled) 16 bits into which you put the 14 bits. Somehow you putting in exact same position (left-hand side instead of right-hand side)

```
Original bits   : 00000011 00100001
Slots 16 bit    : XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
Instead of this : XX000000 11001000 //correct way
You have done   : 00000011 001000XX //wrong way
```

Your right-hand side `XX` are zero so **your result** is 00000011 00100000 which would give **800**, but that's wrong because it's not the true value of those specific 14 bits you extracted.

> *"Is there a more preferred/conventional way of accomplishing what I
>   need?"*

I guess bit-shifting is the conventional way...

Solution (pseudo-code) :

```
var myShort = 0x0321; //Short means 2 bytes
var answer = (myShort >> 2); //bitshift to right-hand side by 2 places
```

By nudging everything 2 places/slots towards right, you can see how the two now-empty places at far-left becomes the XX (automatically zero until you change them), and by nudging you have also just removed the (right-side) 2 bits you wanted to ignore... Leaving you with correct 14-bit value.

**PS:** 
 
Regarding your code... I've not had chance to test it all but the below logic seems more appropriate for your `GetBitArrayFromRange` function :

```
for (int i = 0; i < (length-1); i++)
{
    newBitArray[i] = bitArray.Get(startIndex + i);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my call to GetBitArrayFromRange, I was passing in a startIndex of 2, instead of 0.  So that should clear up why I'm getting the correct value of 800 (and not 200 as you mentioned). I've made the correction to the post above.  I have tested my code with numerous value scenarios and have verified the results to all be correct using my code.  So, this tells me, logically it is correct, however, I was just wondering if there is a better more conventional approach.  Your bitshift example doesn't seem to give me the correct result.

Comment: Are you saying that 14 bits `00000011 001000` (which is essentially `11 001000`) gives you **800**??? What calculator app are you checking this on? I want to test it myself (Windows). For example try this [online **Converter**](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-dec-bin-converter.htm) and in **hex** type your `0321`, now you see the 16 bits (well, leading zeros are always hidden cos $0001 is still one dollar),  so remove the first 2 bits (delete from right-hand side!!) and what is remaining **decimal** value? Also check the bits difference for **decimal** 200 versus **decimal** 800

Comment: PS : _"Your bitshift example doesn't seem to give me the correct result"_ of course it doesn't, why should it? You think a 16 bit value of `0x0321` contains 14 bits that give 800 so why should it?. Actually you only need 10 bits to hold 800 and regardless of `startIndex` as `2` or `0` I'm telling you _**there isn't any 10 (or even 14) bits in sequential order to make an 800 from the bits of : `0x0321`**_ (not even changing Endianness can do it) ...Just double-check everything with a calculator & also `trace` the output of bits before & after each change to see more easily where it goes wrong.

Comment: I'm so sorry, again I had another typo, but SO won't let me edit my post for some reason... I was testing with two values: 0x0320 and 0x321.  The correct result for my 0x321 test is actually: 801. The correct result for 0x0320 is 800.  While my code above does work, I did end up finding the bitshift/bitmask answer I was looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510148/c-sharp-get-specific-bit-and-get-first-14-bits-of-a-ushort-value - Use the code provided and swap out 0x810E for 0x0320, you will get: 800.  Also, use: http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

Comment: Also, the reason you're coming up with 200 is because you're reading from left to right.  Binary is read from right to left, see: http://www.answers.com/Q/Why_do_you_read_binary_digits_right_to_left