# c# - Get Specific Bit and Get first 14 bits of a ushort value

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitmask, ushort

After reading all of the questions and answers on bit shifting/masking, I simply cannot wrap my head around it.  I'm just not understanding how it works on a fundamental level.  I've been able to achieve various techniques by using BitArray and BitConverter instead, but I really would like to understand bit shifting/masking better.

The specific need I have is to do the following:

I have a ushort: **0x810E** (33038)

Using bit shifting/masking, I'd like to know how to:

- Get the 16th bit **Result: 1**
- Get the 15th bit **Result: 0**
- Get a range of bits to create a new ushort value, specifically the
  first 14 bits **Result: 270**

As I said, I'm able to perform these tasks using BitArray which is how I've gotten the correct results, but I'd like to understand how to perform these operations using bit shifting/masking.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Masking single bits**

As you probably know, `ushort` is a 16-bit value, so your given number `0x810E` can also be written as

```
‭10000001 00001110‬
```

Because there is no shifting operator for `ushort`, the value is first converted to `int`.

So, if you want to get the 15th bit, you can take a single bit

```
000000000 0000000 00000000 00000001
```

and shift it 14 times to the left (right side is filled with `0`)

```
00000000 00000000 01000000 00000000
```

and you have created a *bitmask*.

Now if you combine mask and value with an bitwise `and`, you'll get only the value of the 15th bit:

```
  ‭00000000 00000000 10000001 00001110‬
& 00000000 00000000 01000000 00000000
= 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

which is `0` again. To access this bit, you'll have to shift the whole result back to the right 14 times and *cast* it to a `ushort`.

This can be expressed with the following code:

```
ushort value_15 = (ushort)(((1 << 14) & value) >> 14);
```

**Can we do better?**

Although this approach seems to be correct, but there is a simpler way to do this: shift the original value to the right 14 times 
(result is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010`, left side is filled with `0`) and perform a simple bitwise `&` with `1`:

```
  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010 
& 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
= 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

This results in `C#` in:

```
ushort value_15 = (ushort)((value >> 14) & 1);
```

So you avoid one additional shift and we get the same results even when using
*signed numbers* (because there the highest bit, used for the sign, is left unchanged by shifting).

**Masking a bit range**

To mask a bit range, all you have to do is to change your mask. So, to get the value of the lower 14 bits you can use the mask

```
  00000000 00000000 ‭10000001 00001110‬
& 00000000 00000000 00111111 11111111
= 00000000 ‭00000000 00000001 00001110
```

In `C#` this can be expressed with

```
ushort first14bits = (ushort)((0xFFFF >> 2) & value);
```

where (`0xFFFF` is `00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111`).

Comment: Endianness is just a distraction here. It has nothing to do with bit-masking integer values, and is potentially confusing to someone who couldn't bother to do some research on bit-level operations. The syntax and operation is exactly the same, regardless of the length of the single integer value, and regardless of the platform endianness. Also, it's a waste and not at all more "understandable" to do two shifts when one would suffice. It just makes the code repetitive and harder to read.

Comment: Also, there are scenarios using the two-shift approach that could lead a naïve programmer to an implementation that results in a signed value being shifted for the second shift, which could fill in new set bits (in those scenarios, the alternative is to cast e.g. `1 << 63` to `ulong`, but that requires applying `unchecked` to the code, which is less likely for someone who needs bit-shifting explained to them in the first place). A single-shift implementation avoids this, because you are (in the OP's code) starting with an unsigned value, and so no sign bit to be filled in by the shift.

Comment: I've removed the part about endianess. I've tried to create an exhaustive answer but I'll admit that perhaps I focused on unrelevant details. I'm running out of time now, perhaps I'll change the answer later. The one thing _I learned_ (because I was not aware of) that casting is required.

Comment: _"casting is required"_ -- yes, in this case, because the predefined operators don't include one for `ushort`, and the implicit casting rules cast `ushort` to `int` instead of `uint`, thus the result of the shift is `int` and must be cast back to `ushort`. Something like (ushort)(value >> 15 & 1)` would suffice though.

Comment: ventiseis - I really appreciate your explanation.  This helped me a lot...right up until the point of Peter saying that there is an even better way of doing it with single shifts.  I'm going to accept this as the answer, but Peter, I wish you would've followed up with your single shift answer, so we could see the differences, and determine which one is better, more understandable and readable.  Thanks guys!

Comment: I've updated the answer and incorporated Peters suggestions. Thank you for your assistance.